# Deploying node.js project on Google cloud platform

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I've following the rules on these pages to deploy my node.js app on Google:

[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@alkhanif.m/building-your-simple-node-app-and-deploying-it-to-google-cloud-platform-542f507ca749)

[Google Cloud Deploying Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/deploying-web-service)

I've successfully created a project in Google Cloud and created an application.

Back in VS Code, `gcloud init` works, it logs in the correct project in my account. However when I execute `gcloud app deploy`, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy this directory as an App Engine application. Creatine flexible environment) or https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml (App Engine standard environment) under the tab for your language.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [C:\Program Files\React\project5\server] could not be identified as a valid source directory or file.
```

I'm guessing it means my project is missing an yaml file however my node project don't have an app.YAML file but rather app.JS file. How could I deploy my project on Google Cloud?

Comment: Follow the doc: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/writing-web-service#creating_the_appyaml_file

Comment: You may also want to follow https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-nodejs-service and use Cloud Run instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki to help other community members that can encounter this issue:

As stated by @guillaume blaquiere & @Gari Singh:

You need to follow [Writing Your Web Service with Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/writing-web-service#creating_the_appyaml_file) and after creating your `yaml` you should use Cloud Run to build and deploy your application. More information about deployment [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-nodejs-service).